# How to create virtual (in memory) binary files?

Tags: c#, file, stream, binary, in-memory

I'm trying to create the binary files which will be later encrypted and 
will be sent to the server. And I'm using two Windows Services, one to create the Bin files and the other to handle the encryption.

But as the bin files contain sensitive data I do not want the bin files to be created physically on the hard-drive. So, I'm looking for a way to create the bin files virtually which can be encrypted later. As a result the physical binary files on the drive would be the encrypted ones.

This is what I have done so far.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter MyWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FilePath, false);
System.IO.BinaryWriter MyBinWriter = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(MyWriter.BaseStream);

MyBinWriter.Write("Sensitive Data Here");

MyBinWriter.Flush();
MyBinWriter.Close();
```

But this is creating un-encrypted binary files.

Because the services can sometimes stop unexpectedly, it is best if the binary files didn't manifest physically on the hard-drive.

I would like to know what kind of options are available for this requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is not encrypting the file data. So it will be unencrypted only.

Comment: If you want to use a stream with your BinaryWriter which keeps its stuff in **memory**, don't use a file (file stream). Use a ... ... ... ... ... **Memory**Stream (The .NET API documentation will tell you more about MemoryStream and other System.IO types you might need or otherwise might be interested in.)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks for pointing out. I forgot to mention the point. Because the Encryption service will later find these files and start the encryption process. But I'm afraid that when this encryption service is stopped unexpectedly, the bin files will be exposed. What I'm trying to do is to save the binary file stream and send the stream to the encryption windows service. But don't know how to do it or whether it's possible or not.

Comment: @elgonzo Thanks for the comment. That's what I have been trying so far. But as soon as `System.IO.StreamWriter MyWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FilePath, false);` has been executed, the binary file was created. Is `System.IO.StreamWriter` file stream?

Comment: "_Is System.IO.StreamWriter file stream?_" For questions like these, you can use the documentation to answer your question yourself. This is what the documentation is saying about the particular _System.IO.StreamWriter_ constructor you are using: "_Initializes a new instance of the StreamWriter class **for the specified file** [...]_" Now, about whether and how _StreamWriter_ can be used with other streams that are not file streams, i will refer you to the _StreamWriter_ documentation. But then again, **why** do you want to use StreamWriter to begin with?

Comment: StreamWriter can write to stream if you pass stream to it. Look at the constructor options available for StreamWriter [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.8#constructors)

Comment: @elgonzo _why do you want to use StreamWriter to begin with?_ Actually, I inherited the former dev's codes. I'm trying to use the MemoryStream now to see if it works.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks. I will check and try them out.

Comment: @elgonzo Hi, elgonzo. I've just tested it and yep it works. Thanks. Also, I was wondering is there a way to get the stream value to be inserted to the database. Thanks.

Comment: MemoryStream has a ToArray method that returns the content of the MemoryStream as byte array (note that this byte array is a _copy_ of the MemoryStream content, so when dealing with a very large MemoryStream, memory requirements for ToArray() might become an issue). With regard to the database thing i can't help you. Most competent DBMS' allow you to store binary data blobs in a DB, but various restrictions/limitations depending on the actual DBMS you are using might apply. (An alternative would be to store this binary data in a file pool, and let the DB records refer to the file names/paths)

Comment: If using MemoryStream.ToArray is impractical for you, you have two other options that might help you, depending your actual use case: You can simply read the data back from the MemoryStream (just like you would read from any other stream), or you might use MemoryStream's GetBuffer method. However, to correctly use this method, pay utmost attention to what the MemoryStream.GetBuffer documentation tells about the behavior of this method.

Comment: @elgonzo About reading the data back from the MemoryStream, I'm afraid that if the system should shut down, the memory would reset and lose all the data.

Comment: When talking about reading the data back from the MemoryStream, i was _not_ trying to suggest using the MemoryStream as a substitute for the DB storage. I was referring to a possible way to get the data out of the MemoryStream so you can stuff it into the DB ;-)

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean, now. Actually, that's a nice solution. Thanks for the help.